# How to combine two select queries that take place one after the other as one output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Message],[Messagetest]
FROM APM_WindowsEvent_Detail
WHERE EventCode = '4740'
ORDER BY TimeGeneratedUtc DESC
```

That when run shows outputs into the Message column similar to the below:

A user account was locked out.    Subject:   Security ID:  S-1-5-18   Account Name:  MYHSDC14$   Account Domain:  MIDYORKS   Logon ID:  0x3e7    Account That Was Locked Out:   Security ID:  S-1-5-21-2453451309-3470285952-3578167795-501   Account Name:  Guest    Additional Information:   Caller Computer Name: MWMCW75687

I also have another query that I need running once the above has takes place but based off the results of the first query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Message], CHARINDEX('Security ID:  S-1-5-21-', [Message]), LEN([Message])), 'Security ID:  S-1-5-21-', '') AS [Messagetest]
FROM APM_WindowsEvent_Detail
```

So all the information that is displayed before Security ID:  S-1-5-21- is removed and placed into Messagetest column. Now I dont know too much about SQL so I am a little confused as to how to combine these two queries.

After this is done I will want to run a third query as part of this to emmit all text before "Account Name:". I want the 2nd part of the query done first though due to Account Name been referenced twice, there may be another way to do this though but I don't know a great deal about SQL and unsure how to do this, any help appreciated.

--EDIT--

I have solved this now, I didnt realise that when using: AS Messagetest I couldnt run a second query based upon that and the way I have now done it is below:

```
DROP TABLE DOLockoutTest

SELECT SUBSTRING(Message, LEN(LEFT(Message, CHARINDEX ('795-', Message))) + 1, LEN(Message) - LEN(LEFT(Message, CHARINDEX ('795-', Message))) - LEN(RIGHT(Message, LEN(Message) - CHARINDEX ('Additional', Message))) - 1) AS [Messagetest] 
INTO DOLockoutTest
FROM APM_WindowsEvent_Detail
WHERE EventCode IN
(
    SELECT EventCode
    FROM dbo.APM_WindowsEvent_Detail
    WHERE EventCode = '4740'
)


SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Messagetest], CHARINDEX('Account Name:', [Messagetest]), LEN([Messagetest])), 'Account Name:', '') AS [User] 
FROM DOLockoutTest
```

Comment: 1) Which database? looking at `charindex` it looks like `sql server` but confirm. 2) Give some sample data and exact expected output. 3) The output of message column you gave is for one row or multiple rows.

Comment: And which version of SQL Server?

Comment: 1)This is SQL server and the version is 2008 R2 SP3

Comment: 2) The data that is currently in this column would look like the below:

**A user account was locked out.    Subject:   Security ID:  S-1-5-18   Account Name:  MYHSDC12$   Account Domain:  MIDYORKS   Logon ID:  0x3e7    Account That Was Locked Out:   Security ID:  S-1-5-21-2453451309-3470285952-3578167795-95000   Account Name:  David.Test    Additional Information:   Caller Computer Name: MWHAW72256**

and what I want this to look like is: 

**Account Name: David.Test    Additional Information:   Caller Computer Name: MWHAW72256**

Comment: 3) This is for multiple rows of data